# The value of $\int_0^1\ (\prod_{r=1}^n x+r).(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{x+k}).dx $ is

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^1\ (\prod_{r=1}^n x+r).(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{x+k}).dx $$

My working:

$$\int_0^1\ [(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)...(x+n)]\times[\frac{1}{x+1}\ + \frac{1}{x+2}\ + \frac{1}{x+3}\ +\ ...\ + \frac{1}{x+n}].dx \\$$

$\int_0^1[(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)...(x+n)]\ \times\ \frac{[(x+2)(x+3)..(x+n)\ +\ (x+1)(x+3)..(x+n)\ +\ ...\ +\ (x+1)(x+2)..(x+n-1)]}{(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)...(x+n)}.dx\\
$

Now the numerator of the left expression and the denominator of the right expression will cancel out $\\$

$\int_0^1\require{enclose}\enclose{downdiagonalstrike}{[(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)...(x+n)]}\ \times\ \frac{[(x+2)(x+3)..(x+n)\ +\ (x+1)(x+3)..(x+n)\ +\ ...\ +\ (x+1)(x+2)..(x+n-1)]}{\enclose{downdiagonalstrike}{(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)...(x+n)}}.dx$

Now we are left with

$$\int_0^1 [(x+2)(x+3)..(x+n)\ +\ (x+1)(x+3)..(x+n)\ +\ ...\ +\ (x+1)(x+2)..(x+(n-1))].dx$$

I am unable to think of anything after this step although, I have an intuition that it may have something to do with factorials.

Comment: Your intuition is right! see [Rising factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The integrand function is the derivative of $(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+n)=(x+1)_n$, hence the outcome simply is
$$\left[(x+1)_n\right]_{0}^{1}=(n+1)!-n!=n\cdot n!.$$

Comment: What is the meaning of $(x+1)_n$?

Comment: @HarshitBhardwaj: rising Pochhammer symbol, $$(x)_n = x\cdot(x+1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(x+n-1)=n!\binom{x+n-1}{n}$$

Comment: is it the same as writing $^{x+n-1}P_n$?

Comment: thanks I got it now.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$P(x)= \prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}\left(x+k\right)$$
From which
$$P'(x)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\prod\limits_{k=1,k\ne i}^{n}\left(x+k\right)$$
then
$$\frac{P'(x)}{P(x)}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{x+i}$$

As a result
$$\int\limits_0^1 \left(\prod\limits_{r=1}^n (x+r)\right)\cdot \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{x+k}\right)dx =\\
\int\limits_0^1 P(x) \frac{P'(x)}{P(x)}dx=
\int\limits_0^1 P'(x)dx=\\
P(1)-P(0)$$